# Sticky sessions for wl.analytics.url in IBM MobileFirst Platform?

Tags: analytics, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-analytics

We are setting up IBM MobileFirst Platform Analytics at a customer. For resilience and performance, the customer has multiple JVMs hosting the MobileFirst analytics service (which is normally hosted on a context root of something like `worklight-analytics/data`) in a WAS ND cell, and so we need to spray the load from the MobileFirst Platform server to that service using IHS/a load balancer/similar.

Does that spraying need to be sticky in any sense, or should it? If so, what should it be sticky to? I can't think of a logical reason why it would need to be, but (at least until version 7.1) the MobileFirst Platform server itself did need sticky sessions between the client device and the server, so I wanted to validate this *wasn't* the case for the backend analytics service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, stickiness is not required or necessary for MobileFirst Analytics server.  It is completely stateless.